# how to make the red div don't alert 'ss' when drag the black div on it ,

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i using jquery and jquery-ui,

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"> 
</head> 
    <body>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 

        </style>

        <div id=a style="width:300px;height:300px;background:blue;position:absolute;"></div>
        <div id=b style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;position:absolute;"></div>
        <div id=c style="width:50px;height:50px;background:black;clear:both"></div>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8rc3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
$("#c").draggable({});
$("#b").droppable('disable');//this is not useful

$("#a").droppable({
drop: function(event,ui) {
    alert('ss')
    }
});
        </script> 

    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to include the red div inside the blue div in the DOM hierarchy. And then set the droppable of the red div to greedy. Check the documentation on the [droppable plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable)

> If true, will prevent event
>   propagation on nested droppables.

```
$("#c").draggable();
$("#b").droppable({greedy: true});
$("#a").droppable({
  drop: function(event,ui) {
    alert('ss');
  }
});

<div id="a" style="width:300px;height:300px;background:blue;position:absolute;z-index:180">
  <div id="b" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:red;position:absolute;z-index:200"></div>
</div>
<div id="c" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:black;clear:both;z-index:220"></div>
```